# having runtime error with java program

Tags: java

I am given a list of 3 digit numbers and I am trying to see if they are in descending order. The number of elements in the list is not determined but I have set my `SENTINEL` value to be `1000`.

The following error keeps happening though:

```
CompileRunTest: throwable = java.util.NoSuchElementException
java.util.NoSuchElementException
```

My code:

```
import java.util.Scanner ;

public class StrictDescending {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        final int SENTINEL = 1000 ;
        int firstValue = in.nextInt();
        while (firstValue < 1000)
        {
            int secondValue = in.nextInt() ;
            while(secondValue < 1000)
            {
                if(firstValue > secondValue)
                {
                    System.out.println("Yes, the list is in descending order.") ;
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("No, the list is not in descending order.") ;
                }

                secondValue = in.nextInt();
            }

            firstValue = in.nextInt() ;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: your code is ok try again

Comment: That error gets throw if there's no more input to consume. How are you testing it?

Comment: 145
130
125
100
1000 and 145
130
130
125
1000
  those are two different given inputs

Comment: Why declare the `SENTINEL = 1000;` if you aren't using it anywhere?

Comment: trying to make the loop stop when a 4 digit number is entered or the numbers arent descending

Comment: Do not vandalize your post.

Comment: sorry was trying to make a new post

Comment: @javahelp try the big button on the top right;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try switching the first while to an if statement, add  `firstValue = secondValue` on the line before `secondValue = in.nextInt();`
 and remove the last `firstValue = in.nextInt();` You'll need to mess around with your print statement a little as well.

As it is your program flow doesn't quite make sense since you will try to consume from stdin even when there are no numbers left.

Comment: okay i did that for the inputs 145
130
125
100
1000 and it gave me Yes, the list is in descending order  (3 times repeated)

Comment: I'll let you figure that part out. I can't do all your homework for you ;)

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED ANSWER**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int previousValue = getInt(sc);
    while(Math.abs(previousValue) < 1000) {
        if (previousValue <= (previousValue = getInt(sc))) {
            System.out.println("No, the list is not in descending order.");
            break;
        }
        System.out.println("Yes, the list is in descending order.");
    }
}

public static int getInt(Scanner sc) {
    if (sc.hasNextInt()) {
        return sc.nextInt();
    }
    sc.next();
    System.out.println("Type only numbers, please.");
    return getInt(sc);
}
```

---

If you want that the message prints after you stop typing numbers (by typing a value >= than 1000), the following could be a possible solution (equal values do not support descending order):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    Integer previousValue = getInt(sc);
    boolean descending = false;
    while(previousValue != null) {
        Integer currentValue = getInt(sc);
        if (currentValue != null) {
            if (previousValue > (previousValue = currentValue)) {
                if (!descending) { // if not yet true
                    descending = !descending; // set true
                }
            } else {
                descending = false; // to print: "No, ..."
                previousValue = null; // to break the loop
            }
        } else {
            previousValue = currentValue; // it's actually null
        }
    }
    System.out.println((descending)
        ? "Yes, the list is in descending order." 
        : "No, the list is not in descending order.");
}

public static Integer getInt(Scanner sc) {
    if (!sc.hasNextInt()) {
        sc.next();
        System.out.println("Type only numbers, please.");
        return getInt(sc);
    }
    int input = sc.nextInt();
    return (Math.abs(input) < 1000) ? input : null;
}
```

Comment: I am trying to compare x amount of numbers, the x value isnt given

Comment: says just a list of numbers

Comment: But do you mean it stops when next int is greater or equal to the previous one? Or maybe I don't understand the problem. I need more details.

Comment: @javahelp I'm sorry. You wrote 3 DIGIT numbers, and not 3 numbers ")

Comment: thanks for your time   so given a list of three digit integrs, i need to make sure the list is in strictly descending order, if a number is not in descending order it should stop and print out no, the numbers are not in descending order  and consecutive numbers that are equal are not in descneding order

Comment: Yes, the list is in descending order.
Yes, the list is in descending order.
Yes, the list is in descending order.
No, the list is not in descending order.

Comment: i get that input when i plug in 145
130
125
100
1000

Comment: One more thing I had to edit. This is important: 'sc.next();" Otherwise you'd get StackOverflowError if you did not type digits.

Comment: Yes, the list is in descending order.
Yes, the list is in descending order.
Yes, the list is in descending order.
No, the list is not in descending order.

Comment: @javahelp, look at the second option (I've edited my answer again)

Comment: @javahelp do you need equal values to support descending order? E.g. 900 900 800 or 900 800 800